# Awk doesn't represent ip addresses correctly

Tags: awk, ip

I have done bash script for sorting extreme switches ports:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/bin/visiextreme.txt" 

while read ip
do
    a=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c test $ip ifDescr | column -t >> /bin/alias.txt )
    b=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c test $ip ifAlias | awk '{print '$ip' " " $4 }' | column -t >> /bin/descr.txt ) 
done < "$file"

c=$( paste /bin/alias.txt /bin/descr.txt | awk ' /'tr_'/{print $7 " " $6 " " $8}' | column -t >> /bin/aliasdescr.txt )
```

`visiextreme.txt` is filled with ip addresses:

```
10.1.96.21
10.1.96.22
192.168.0.24
....
```

Why after command `| awk '{print '$ip' " " $4 }' |` I get output:

```
10.10.960.21
10.10.960.22
192.16800.24
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that there is a slash `/` in front of the file name in `done</"$file"`

Comment: Try `awk -vip="$ip" '{print ip" "$4 }'`

Comment: You seem very confused about shell scripting - storing temp files in /bin, jumping in/out of awk for no reason (`awk ' /'tr_'/`), invoking column multiple times for no apparent reason, unquoting variables for no apparent reason, storing nothing in a variable `c` at the end of the script, etc. If you'd like help to write a script to do what you want, post another question with sample input and expected output and tell us what `snmpwalk` outputs.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. After Hakon's answer, script does what i want. Ed,relax, everything in my script has a reason and script does what i want.

Answer (score 3):

The preferred way to pass arguments from bash to awk is to supply them on the command line using the `-v` option. Like:

```
awk -vip="$ip" '{print ip" "$4 }'
```

This would solve your problem. However, you could still use your approach,
but then we must put double quotes around the argument to `print`.

Notice that the following (taken from your question):

```
awk '{print '$ip' " " $4 }'
```

expands to

```
awk '{print 10.1.96.21 " " $4}'
```

This is obviously not what we intended. So we need to put double quotes around `10.1.96.21` to make `print` understand that we want to print the string `10.1.96.21` and not the number `10.1`. So this is a solution:

```
awk '{print "'$ip' " $4 }'
```

If you do not have double quotes around `10.1.96.21` the dots seems to expand to zeros (!) inside awk. For example:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print 1.2.3.4}'
```

gives

```
1.20.30.4
```

(Anybody who can explain this behavior?)

Comment: I think it would be best to put `awk -vip=$ip '{print ip " " $4}'` at the top of your answer, and then explain what he did wrong. I dropped the quotes around `$ip` because they shouldn't be needed, and adjusted the spacing within `{...}` for readability. In any case, +1 ;-)

Comment: What you wrote is 3 numbers (represented by `1.2`, `.3`, and `.4`) concatenated so awk converts the numbers to `1.2`, `0.3`, and `0.4` per it's normal conversion rules (try `print .2`) and concatenates the result so you get `1.20.30.4`.